# Adding service reference of a hosted wcf service which is containing multiple running services

Tags: c#, wcf

a service is having multiple services which are hosed and started successfully, when i am trying with WCFTESTCLIENT tool i am getting the error "unable to get the metadata of the service plese check the service  is running and exposing metadata". what are the tools we can use to troubleshoot this kind of problems in WCF service.
please help .

Comment: Did you enable tracing? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: thanks david. i will check with this tracing technique.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cause of the problem is in hosting process.unfortunately i commented the line servicehostObject.open() method in OnStart method. we can check the hosting process by using " ***netstat -a*** " command in VS command prompt. i have checked with this command, and came to know that the address/port was not there.but other ports with tcp protocol was there and also in listening status. so concluded that service not yet hosted. then i checked my windows Service hosting programs onStart method by using ***debugger.lauch()***.
and finally got the issue problem and fixed successfully. the problem is simple :D
 i commented the service open method. like below.
//servicehostObject .open();

but this mistake gave the opportunity to learn about tracing. yeah issues/problems only help us to learn more always.

while using wcftestclient try to give the exact address of the service. 
***localhost/ip address*** make sure on this mainly.